# Harddrive disappearing intermittenly

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, ssd, windows-10, sata

Thanks in advance for helping

I am currently facing a problem with my hard drive that I had for over two years now. It is a WD green 3TB running on windows 7 as a secondary to a Samsung SSD that have windows on it. It had no problem until about 2 months ago where it will disappear from "My Computer". If I restart the computer it still wont show, but if I unplug the SATA cable and replug it and then turn the computer on, it will show for a while but eventually it will disappear again.

I recently updated to Windows 10 and the problem still exists.

Comment: You are reaching the end of the warranty period.  Which supports the fact your problems are hardware not software releated

Comment: While I wouldn't quite go so far as to say it is factually a hardware problem, based on the information provided, I would certainly lean towards a hardware issue vs. software.

Comment: Do you have another computer to try it on?

Comment: @N.Greene No, I do not actually, all my other computers are Macs. Ramhound & Scott Johnson I also am leaning towards hardware problem, should I just get a new hard drive? Or attempt to fix it.

Comment: I agree with everyone, that is most likely hardware problem, but it could also be a power supply issue.

Comment: @N.Greene - So eliminate that possibility.  Its very unlikely it is that though.

Comment: @DanielChen Change the SATA cable to another port on the mobo(you may need to enable it in BIOS too) and test. If it resolves the issue great but if it doesnt then its most likely the PCB on the drive itself. They arent economical to repair so replace the drive at that point. A bad 12v rail without system stability issues is quite unlikely.

Comment: @Linef4ult Thanks, that sounds like a great next step.

Comment: @DanielChen A cheaper hardware problem could be the SATA data cable itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I connected the HD to another SATA port on the motherboard and so far it is working.

Thanks all for helping

Answer (score 0):

The others provided you with some pretty good troubleshooting steps already. However, I'd also recommend you to test the HDD's health and SMART status using WD's Data LifeGuard Diagnostics for Windows. Running the QUICK and EXTENDED tests will tell you if there's something wrong with the WD Green itself. [Here's a link to it](http://support.wdc.com/downloads.aspx?lang=en).